Is fingerprints biometric authentication supported in flutter web?
I'm building a web verification system with flutter. And it requires biometric data capturing like fingerprints, but the problem is no biometric (fingerprints) package support flutter web. Is there a solution?
I've checked all other packages but none support flutter web. We

checkout fingerprintjs if it is working for you.
